# Grammatical mistake in the Gita

Tags: cases, sanskrit

I am studying Sanskrit. I encountered a sentence in verse 19 of chapter 1 of the Bhagavad gita - as it is. The sloka is as follows:

```
स घोषो धार्तराष्ट्राणां हृदयानि व्यदारयत्।
नभश्च पृथिवीं चैव तुमुलोऽभ्यननुदयन्।।
```

As per the translation in the book, the verse means as follows:

```
The hearts of the sons of Dhritarashtra were shattered as the 
tumultuous sound reverberated throughout the sky and on the land.
```

In the latter line नभः is in the first case whereas पृथिवीं is in the second case? How is this possible? Isn't the पृथिवी also the subject? Shouldn't it be just पृथिवी as per the declension rules of पृथिवी?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

नभः is accusative (second case), like पृथिवीं. The subject is तुमुलो.

Comment: Oh nabhas is the root. I thought it was nabha